# How to access url from event attributes and perform external redirect in spring webflow

Tags: java, spring, jsf, xhtml, spring-webflow

I have a use case where I need to redirect to an external URL via spring webflow, the url might change every time the user clicks on the link. I am trying to use externalRedirect within the flow.xml and passing in the url in a localAttributeMap and returning it with the event.

The summary.xhtml code looks something like this.

```
<h:commandLink action="redirect" target="_blank">
Redirect to new page
</h:commandLink>
```

The flow.xml is something like this:

```
<view-state id="summary" view="/flows/forms/summary.xhtml">
  <transition on="redirect" to="retrieveUri" />
</view-state>

<action-state id="retrieveUri">
  <evaluate expression="redirectAction.execute(requestContext, formContext)" />
  <transition on="successRedirect" to="externalView" />
</action-state>

<view-state id="externalView" view="externalRedirect:#{currentEvent.attributes.redirectUrl}">
</view-state>
```

On the code base I am using I am forced to only use Actions which extend MultiAction and I can't use any other service have return types like String. My action class with the execute method which returns an Event looks something like below:

```
public Event execute(RequestContext context, FormContext formContext) {
  LocalAttributeMap lam = new LocalAttributeMap() ;
  lam.put("redirectUrl", "https://google.com") ;
//Above would of course be replaced with some service layer call but I need to redirect to this url and that too via classes extending MultiAction. 
  return new Event(this, " successRedirect", lam) ;
}
```

However this does not seem to work for me and I am getting the below errors:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.binding.expression.EvaluationExpression : An ElException occured getting the value for expression 'currentEvent.attributes.redirectUrl' on context [class org.springftamework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl]
  at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringElExpression.getValue(SpringElExpression.java:92) 
  at org.springframework.webflow.action.ExternalRedirectAction.doExecute(ExternalRedirectAction.java:42) 
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationExpression : EL1007E:(pos 13):  Property or field 'attributes' cannot be found on null
  at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:208) 
  at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:85)
  at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:78)
```

Being new to spring webflow, I am not sure of the issue and would appreciate some help in understanding the issue and whether is the correct way of using this.
The version of spring-webflow is 2.3.0.RELEASE within the project

Comment: try putting it in flowscope instead

Comment: So the URL is supposed to change for each and every single request and since the new URL is supposed to open it up a new tab, the user needs to have the option to go back to the original tab and to click on the link again and a fresh url should be opened up in another new tab again. I am worried that since the scope of the flow scope will be throughout that session if that might cause issues (feel free to correct me if that is not the case). Adding it to flowScope would have been the first choice if the url had been a static url which means it would be same throughout the session for the user.

Comment: hmm, could you try using `<set name="currentEvent.attributes.redirectUrl" value="action.returnUrlValue()">` and not create the new event etc.?

Comment: so after a lot of digging around through the documentation of the spring webflow, I found a good substitute to the flowScope and it seems that flashScope can be used in this case, since the flashScope gets cleared after every view render and that is the behavior I would want to see in the application so that is what I have been using now. So this would mean that although the URL would change after every view render, since the scope would be cleared by that time, I won't be overriding existing values in the scope